# AWS Athena Query Structure

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have a complex type and I want to query it using Athena

> {id={s=c937b52e-fee8-4899-ae26-d4748e65fb5f}, __typename={s=Account}, role={s=COLLABORATOR}, updatedat={s=2021-04-23T04:38:29.385Z}, entityid={s=70f8a1a8-6f20-4dd3-a484-8385198ddf97}, status={s=ACTIVE}, createdat={s=2021-04-23T04:38:20.045Z}, email={s=dd@mail.com}, showonboarding={bool=true}, position={s=beta}, name={s=User2}, lastlogindate={s=2021-04-23T04:41:07.775Z}}

How to do it?

```sql
SELECT c.*
FROM "db"."table" c
LIMIT 10
```

returns all data in the table. However if I select like

```
SELECT c.id
FROM "db"."table" c
LIMIT 10
```

it shows the error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:8: Column 'c.id' cannot be resolved
This query ran against the "analytics-db" database, unless qualified by the query.

Comment: Can you please add result for `SELECT c.* FROM "db"."table" c LIMIT 1` ?

Comment: Sure
Result is:

{id={s=47d7f35e-cff0-462b-ae8b-3500b524133a}, __typename={s=Account}, role={s=ADMIN}, updatedat={s=2021-07-09T01:53:10.296Z}, entityid={s=8bbd9eeb-74bf-474a-b65a-415a831246a0}, status={s=ACTIVE}, createdat={s=2021-07-09T01:29:20.222Z}, email={s=dd@mail.com}, showonboarding={bool=true}, position={s=Leadership}, name={s=GZ}, lastlogindate={s=2021-11-04T23:26:49.262Z}}

Comment: And the column names row? You are missing column name in your query: `c.id` should be `c.some_column_name.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is missing name for column which stores the shown data. You should change your query to something like:

```sql
SELECT c.some_column_name.id -- use real column name instead of some_column_name
FROM "db"."table" c
LIMIT 10
```